# C++ compile with Filesystem library

Tags: c++, g++, filesystems, c++17

### Note:

It turns out that this question has been asked before. However, the answer to the duplicate question uses an old workaround. As commented by "Mat" below, these days we can just make sure that we're using a newer compiler. For `gcc` we need at least `version 8`:

```
g++-8 -std=c++17 demo.cpp
```

And assumedly something similar in `clang`/`msvc`.

### Original question:

I want to be able to use the C++17 Filesystem library

I am compiling using bash as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++17 demo.cpp
```

the demo.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main () 
{
    return 0;
}
```

The code is really just a simplified version of what's listed on cppreference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path

However the code for me won't compile, with the following error:

```
fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
```

I am currently using: gcc version 5.5.0 20171010 (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04)

If my command prompt is incorrect, could you please tell me what I'm missing? preferably still using g++?

Otherwise could you tell me if it works on your system? (so that I know that this is an issue with my compiler)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017 - implemented in GCC 8 if I read the table correctly.

Comment: In pre 8 gcc it is experimental/filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Mat! "g++-8 -std=c++17 demo.cpp" works!

Thanks aman5319, I had looked for answers, but this question *is* effectively the same. It's a shame that this questions appeared unanswered (the only response is a workaround). I will update this as answered.